Запуск нескольких потоков интернет радио в cvlc linux
Хочу создать демонов для запуска двух одновременных потоков с разными портами. Как пишут в интернете должно работать, но у меня работает только один поток, а другой не работает хотя линукс пишет что демон активный, по ссылке радио второе не работает.
Вот код двух демонов.
Первый:
[Unit]
Description=VLC Streaming FKJ
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/cvlc /home/xyz/Music/Synthwave_Retrowave/SR.m3u --sout '#transcode{acodec=vorb,ab=256,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:http{mux=ogg,dst=:8550/sr_stream.ogg}' --loop --sout-x-fade-time=2000 --random
Restart=always
RestartSec=5

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

Второй:
[Unit]
Description=VLC Streaming FKJ
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/cvlc /home/xyz/Music/FKJ/FKJ.m3u --sout '#transcode{acodec=vorb,ab=256,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:http{mux=ogg,dst=:8500/fkj_stream.ogg}' --loop --sout-x-fade-time=2000 --random
Restart=always
RestartSec=5

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

Помогите плиз. ОС: Ubuntu 24

Не по теме вопроса, но на всякий случай рекомендую вынести длинную команду в отдельный bash-скрипт, а уже этот bash-скрипт запускать через systemd, чтобы не было необходимости редактировать демон на каждый чих

А по теме вопроса - если вы демона таки редактировали, не забыли ли вы сделать daemon-reload после этого, например?

@andreymal reload делаю всегда когда редакчу файл. а за bash скрипт спасибо. почитаю подробнее.

Ну тогда давайте дебажить по шагам - в чём именно проявляется неработоспособность? Прописанный вами http-порт вообще принимает соединения хотя бы например?

@andreymal Решил проблемы. 1. Косяк был в параметре запуска. 2. Файл плейлист у потока который как бы работал а не работал заключалась в ошибке при оформлении файла. Спасибо что подсказал про bash-скрипт. )

В общем решил я свою проблему. Заключалась в том что --sout-x-fade-time=2000 уже оказывается не актуальный параметр запуска потока. (Используйте --sout-keep чтобы при переключении файла поток оставался единым и не прерывался.). Второе проверяйте если создаете файлы плейлисты чтобы правильно оформлены были.
